# Grouping by columns and rows in data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table

I am quite new to r so apologies if this is basic (I am sure it is) but I haven’t been able to find an answer anywhere.

I have a data set showing individual product sales with about 500,000 rows and 30 columns, including region, sale amount, and date.  I am using basic data.table functionality to create summaries based on single groups, like sales by date and sales by region(i.e. DT[,sum(Sales),by=Date]), which look like:

```
Date    Sales
12/1    50,000
12/2    70,000
12/3    40,000
```

And

```
Region  Sales
North   67000
East    60000
South   15000
West    22000
```

What I’d like to do is view (for example) sales broken down by region and date, so something like:

```
        12/1    12/2    12/3
North   10,000  15,000  12,000
East    5,000   25,000  30,000
South   2,000   3,000   10,000
West    6,000   7,000   9,000
```

I’d like to be able to do this for all dates included in the file ( so I don’t need to change it manually every time I run this for different data sets and dates).  Is this possible with data.table or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: @akrun that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  One more question - is there a way to include a condition in the value.var field?  Say I want to count the number of sales to new customers by region and date - in my first example that would be DT[,sum(NewCustomer=="YES"),by=Date]), to view it by date.  Can that condition be incorporated into the dcast statement?

Comment: You can try `dcast(DT[NewCustomer == "YES"], Region~Date, length)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large datasets, the `dcast` from `data.table` should be efficient.

```
dcast(DT, Region~Date, value.var="Sales", sum)
```

NOTE: Here, we assume the 'Sales' as `numeric` class.  From the data showed in the example, there are `,` between numbers.  So, it could be non-numeric.  If it non-numeric, convert to `numeric` after removing the `,`

```
DT[, Sales := as.numeric(gsub(",", "", Sales))]
```

and then do the `dcast`